# Adding up total in a class file

Tags: java, oop

I'm pretty new to OOP, so any help is appreciated. I have a class file that takes some inputs and calculates the area of a triangle like such:

```
public class Triangle
{
    private int base;
    private int height;
    private double area;
    private String name;
    private double totalArea = 0;


    public void writeOutput()
    {
        System.out.println("Triangle name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Triangle base: " + base);
        System.out.println("Triangle height: " + height);
        System.out.println("Triangle area: " + setArea());
        System.out.println("Total Area: " + totalArea);
    }

    private double setArea()
    {
        area = (base * height) * 0.5;
        return area;
    }

    private double setTotalArea()
    {
        totalArea += area;
        return totalArea;
    }
}
```

My problem is in the `setTotalArea()` method. Basically, it is supposed to add up a cumulative total of all the areas calculated, however, all it is doing is echoing the area and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up setters and getters. For instance, your `setArea()` method is not a true "setter" method as it is private, accepts no parameter, sets nothing, and tries to return a value -- the exact opposite of most things a setter should do, and the same goes for your setTotalArea.

Anyway, sorry to say, but this code is borked, and I recommend you simply get rid of it and start over (it's not that big of a class yet, so this is no big deal), but start with your fields (height, base, and name), the constructor, perhaps one that sets class properties and with true *public* setter methods that actually accept parameters and use those parameters to set class fields. Then create your getter methods that return the values of the class fields. Your class shouldn't even have a setArea method or an area field since the area is a calculated value, not a set value, ant it should probably be calculated on the spot in the getArea() method and returned.

Edit, you state:

> My problem is in the setTotalArea() method. Basically, it is supposed to add up a cumulative total of all the areas calculated, however, all it is doing is echoing the area and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Sorry, but I don't understand this. total of what areas? The class only describes one triangle and so there is no cumulative area concept here. Now if you have another class that holds an array or collection of Triangle objects, then a ***get***TotalArea (not *set* total area) method would make sense as it would add the areas of all triangles in the collection, but  you don't have this here.

Comment: Well I was trying to follow a UML diagram given for this assignment, but maybe something got lost in translation. Everything was working, except for the part I mentioned above. what `setTotalArea()` was supposed to do was add up all the areas calculated. For example, if area1 = 3, area2 = 5, and area3 = 8, the `totalArea` should equal 16 (3 + 5 + 8).

Comment: Regardless of whether it's working or not, it's completely wrong. And what are area1, area2, and area3? Sorry but this still makes no sense. You might want to post the actual assignment text and the UML because you must be interpreting it wrong.

Comment: Well I was just using that as an example for what `setTotalArea()` should do. Either way, I guess I'll just start over on the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew: get total area should not be a method of the class since the class does not describe a collection of areas, but rather only describes *one* area. Again, I fear you are grossly misinterpreting your instructions but without seeing those instructions, that's about all any of us can say.

Comment: Rewrote this with a fresh perspective this morning, and am happy to report it is working correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clear to your execution but if -
Triangle t1 = new Triangle(); t1.setArea();
Triangle t2 = new Triangle(); t2.setArea();

Above 2 are seperate Objects , If you are using the above kind of Object creation , then you can not expect to get cumulative total as both object have their own copy of setArea method.

Comment: Yes, three separate objects are being created in the driver file. Would there be a way to find the total of all three objects somehow?

Comment: by giving the driver class a method that iterates through an array of Triangles. I told  you this already in my answer.

Comment: Actually there is something called static keyword available in java, you can create a variable static and then on every object instance in the end of the area method, you can add like static int areaSum = 0; and areaSum = areaSum+totalarea ***Static is not the only solution and for proper coding we must avoid using static , but FYI I am just mentioning you a way to achieve